# Table list is coming empty in Amazon glue catalogue when we request amazon glue client

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to implement https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-genai-datamesh/blob/main/blogs/Simple-text-to-sql/mda_with_llm_langchain_byo_model_without_cloudformation.ipynb

Basically it is creating a crawler for s3 bucket and creating Glue crawler for the s3 bucket.
In code its creating glue_db_name='genai-workshop200'
But when I try to get tables it giving emptry list

```
    def parse_catalog():
        #Connect to Glue catalog
        #get metadata of redshift serverless tables
        columns_str=''
    
        #define glue cient
        glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
    
        for db in gdc:
            response = glue_client.get_tables(DatabaseName =db)
            print(response)
            for tables in response['TableList']:
                print(tables)
```

Table list comes empty like this - `'TableList': []`

I follow the same steps as in code given in above link but still I dont see tables created. Am I missing any thing. Any suggestion to solve this issue

I follow the same steps as in code given in above link but still I dont see tables created. Am I missing any thing. Any suggestion to solve this issue